# How to add js file based on window width?

Tags: javascript

I want to add js file only if my screen is less than 800.How could its possible.
I have following code snippet:

```
<script> localhost/script/test1.js</script>
```

i want to add test1.js if width greater than 800.
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: What should happen if the window is <800 when the page loads and then expands to be more than 800?

Comment: i want to add test1.js only if window width > 800 ..Thanks

Comment: You didn't answer my question. What if the window changes size after the fact? Why are you trying to do this? It sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @SINGHKD There are two answers below for you. I have posted an answer that caters for a window resize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this here: 
1. Check what's the window inner width.
2. Create a new script element and set the attributes you need.
3. Append the new created element to head.

```
 if(window.innerWidth < 800){
      var fileToLoad=document.createElement('script')
      fileToLoad.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
      fileToLoad.setAttribute("src", filename)
      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileToLoad)
  }
```